# How do I add list into body of email template via html tags using apps script? Not looking to make entire body of email html

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created an email template on another tab in sheets. This template essentially lists out the grades of many exams taken. I figure it would be as simple as making a simple html template but it does not work.

this currently lies in a cell as variable messageBody1

```
Hello {Name},

Your requested grades for the {For} for the language {Lang Exam 1}, and exam {Exam 1} are below.

Exam name: {Exam 1}, # of grades: {Num Exam 1}

Your grades are 

<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li> {data}
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Where {data} has A,B,C,D,F,A,B.

I would like it to list instead as

A

B

C

I've tried the below but it doesnt seem to list the grades in Gmail.

```
var messageBody1 = bodyTemplateExam1LangExam1.replace(/{Name}/g,Name).replace(/{data}/g,data).replace("{For}",For).replace(/{Exam 1}/g,Exam1).replace(/{Lang Exam 1}/g,LangExam1).replace(/{Num Exam 1}/g,NumExam2);
if (Exam1 == "Math 2" && LangExam1 == "Spanish"){
   MailApp.sendEmail(Email,subjectLine, messageBody1);}
```

Comment: Read [mre]. Your code is not reproducible. Provide dummy data for all undeclared variables in your code, especially `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data input is a string defined as "A,B,C,D,F,A,B".

If you want to display your {data} as a list within your html body, a way to do it would to assign “data” to an array, whereby each comma separated entry of data would be assigned to an array element. Then you would loop through the array and enclose each of the elements within the `<li> </li>` tags and append all the enclosed elements to a string that will replace your placeholder {data}. This is what the code could look like:

```
    function myFunction() {

  var bodyTemplateExam1LangExam1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();

  var Name="testname";
  var data="A,B,C,D,F,A,B";
  var For="homework";
  var Exam1="Math 2";
  var LangExam1="Spanish";
  var NumExam2=2;

  var Email="testmail@test.com";
  var subjectLine="exam results";

  var dataArray=data.split(",");
  var list="";
  dataArray.forEach(function(element) 

   list=list+"<li>"+element+"</li>";
  })
  var messageBody1 = bodyTemplateExam1LangExam1.replace(/{Name}/g,Name).replace(/{data}/g,list).replace("{For}",For).replace(/{Exam 1}/g,Exam1).replace(/{Lang Exam 1}/g,LangExam1).replace(/{Num Exam 1}/g,NumExam2);
  if (Exam1 == "Math 2" && LangExam1 == "Spanish")

    Logger.log(messageBody1)
    MailApp.sendEmail 
    ({
      to: Email,
      subject: subjectLine,
      htmlBody: messageBody1
    })
  }  
}
```

With the following content contained in cell A1:

```
<p>
Hello {Name},

Your requested grades for the {For} for the language {Lang Exam 1}, and exam {Exam1} are below.

Exam name: {Exam 1}, # of grades: {Num Exam 1}

Your grades are 
<ul>
{data}
</ul>
</p>
```

(You do not need the full  notation and can leave most of the tags you don’t use out).